# How to escape strings in MySQL Document Store find expression?

Tags: c#, mysql, escaping, nosql

I am playing around with the MySQL Document Store and I can't figure out how to properly escape strings with special characters in find statements.

Visual C# 2015
Connector/NET: 8.0.8.0

```
var realmName = "Aman'Thul";
var realm = collection.Find("Name = :name")
    .Bind("name", realmName).Limit(1).Execute().FetchOne();

=> System.ArgumentException: Unterminated string starting at 4
```

The issue is obviously the apostrophe, but the same results come up with other "special characters" like brackets, hyphens and so on.

Version #2:

```
var realmName = "Aman''Thul";
var realm = collection.Find("Name = :realmName").Bind("realmName", realmName).Limit(1).Execute().FetchOne();

=> System.ArgumentException: Only 1 tokens consumed, out of 3
```

Version #3:

```
var realmName = "Aman\\'Thul";
var realm = collection.Find("Name = :realmName").Bind("realmName", realmName).Limit(1).Execute().FetchOne();

=> System.ArgumentException: Can't parse at pos: 4
```

At this point I am out of ideas. What is the right way to correctly escape those expressions? There has to be some general solution I can't seem to find, because information about MySQL Document Store is sparse.

Comment: I'm only guessing, but going off the documentation, you escape an apostrophe with another apostrophe, so for this: `my'name` you'd put `my''name`.  However, different version have different escape methods, there's also the `\'` option that you've already tried (though only one slash, not two).

Comment: Double apostrophes are my version #2 and don't work. Single backslash to escape the apostrophe leads to the same error as Version #1.

Comment: It's an obvious thing, but have you tried this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences  but for your version?

Comment: Ah! Have you tried this:  `var realmName = "\"Aman'Thul\"";`  Because apparently, it auto-escapes this string for you, but you may still need to wrap that auto-escaped string in a string literal yourself.  (Or maybe with single quotes to wrap it, I'm not sure).

Comment: I did check the docs, but those are for standard SQL queries and didn't work in this case.

Comment: Wow, escaping the escaped string. What a treat. `var realmName = "\"Aman'Thul\"";`actually works. Thank you.

Comment: Added Answer to question now we've figured it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments - It appears you need to wrap the words in a string literal yourself, as it doesn't do this automatically.  It DOES escape the contents of that string though, so no need to escape anything for MySQL reasons, only escape for C# reasons.  Like this:

```
var realmName = "\"Aman'Thul\"";
```